# Node Express says EADDRINUSE But port is free

Tags: node.js, express

When trying to start my node express service, I am having trouble with the infamous error "listen EADDRINUSE."

Here's the line where I attempt to call listen:

```
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("listening on port %d", server.address().port);
});
```

The thing is, I can't find any other node process running, nor does anything show running on port 3000.

Here are the results I get for those inquiries:

```
$ ps aux | grep node
ec2-user  7780  0.0  0.0 110280   848 pts/1    S+   17:41   0:00 grep node

$ nestat -anp | grep 3000
<nothing>
```

This is quite baffling. I could try to recycle the box, but it's running a live site and I'm reluctant to do that.

Is there anything else I can do to try to troubleshoot this?

EDIT: Thanks, Ali, for suggesting the obvious thing that I somehow missed. I am now up and running on port 3300. But, when I check netstat I don't see 3300 in there either. Which suggests to me that I have some sort of process running on 3000 that I don't know how to find. For the record, this is an AWS Linux AMI.

Comment: did you try with another port like 3300,3001 etc?

Comment: Oh man, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Okay, it does work on a different port, and thank you for suggesting that. It gets me around my development block. But it concerns me that I seem to have an open port that Node doesn't think is open.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question. Are you absolutely sure you're running those commands on the box the node script is trying to start?

Comment: Also try with `sudo`, perhaps you started it with elevated permissions?

Comment: try to grep with different keyword like ps aux | grep app.js or  ps aux | grep nodejs... because i knew i have experience that same issue on AWS

Answer (score 4):

Maybe your process doesn't stop while you are stopping your program in those ports.
try to run these commands in your terminal.

```
lsof -i:<your port number>
```

If you got a table then it means your process is not killed, copy that PID from that table and run this command

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

this will kill the process running on that port, after this, you can use this port for your program.